# Zip Three Different Mono of Different Type

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I have started a new project using Spring Webflux and I am fairly new to this reactive coding paradigm. So apologies in advance for questioning like newbies.

My controller method returns the response as `Mono<ResponseEntity<String>>` and I have three different services to call from where I am getting three different `Mono` object like this -

```
Mono<CustomObject> customMono = serivce1.method();
Mono<Boolean> booleanMono = service2.method();
Mono<String> stringMono = service3.method();
```

So in order prepare the response(`Mono<ResponseEntity<String>>`), I need to do something like this -

```
Mono.zip(customMono, booleanMono, stringMono, (customData, booleanData, stringData) -> {
------
return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok().body("-----"));
});
```

The problem is, there are no such `zip` method to take 3 `Mono` and a function as parameters. I already found thise -
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-java.util.function.BiFunction-

but it doesn't fulfil my requirement. So issues I am facing

- I can not use *Mono.mergeWith* or *Mono.concaWith* method because my Mono object are of different kind.
- I can flatMap/map every Mono and create a chain. But I want service2 to be called parallel in a separate thread as it is not dependent on service1 call. But service3 call is dependent on service1 response.

In summary, what I need to do:

- make service1 call at first
- make service2 call separately on different thread
- make service3 call which is dependent on service1 call data
- generating the final response object (`Mono<ResponseEntity<String>>`) using the data from all the service call.

Thanks in advance. As a newbie, any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For your specific condition, you need `Mono.zipWhen()` which will ensure that your 3rd service call will have the data it requires from the response from service call 1

```
Mono.zip(monoResponse1,monoResponse2).zipWhen(data ->serviceCall3(data.getT1())).flatMap(response ->{
    response.getT1().getT1();//response from mono1
    response.getT1().getT2();//response from mono 2
    response.getT2();//response from mono 3
    return {create your mono response here};
} );
```

Comment: Thank you. can you please suggest a way how can I make the service2 call parallel/asynchronous? When I call the Mono.zip method, I want service2 response ready to be used right then.

Comment: you can use service2 response right there by using data.getT2()

Answer (score 34):

Whenever you zip the two mono then the third parameter will be `BiFunction` but with three-parameter, it returns a `flatmap` of `tuple` then in the tuple you will get the response of other Monos.
You need to modify your code in the below manner.

```
Mono.zip(customMono, booleanMono, stringMono).flatMap(data->{
 data.getT1();
 data.getT2();
 data.getT3();
 return <your_response_object>;
});
```

Now what will be the return type of `getT1()`,`getT2()` and `getT3()` ?

Obusally it will depend on what your **Zip Mono** return.

Hope so it will help you.

Comment: can you please suggest a way how can I make the service2 call parallel/asynchronous? When I call the Mono.zip method, I want service2 response ready to be used right then.

Comment: i think below Yash answer had a same solutions.

Comment: Can you please clarify why you used `flatMap` instead of `map` and what does the `Mono.just` do at end, compared to simply returning `<your_response_object>`?

Comment: what to do when there is more than 8 mono? the max is 8 for mono.zip

Comment: @GaudamThiyagarajan then you need to call data.getT8() hope it will work. Zip up to 8 elements and request data up to T8().

Answer (score 0):

I am also in my Reactive programming learning phase. So I started with doing zipWith on 2 method and started thinking what if I want to zip more than 2 methods!

I found out that I can chain the method with another zipWith.

```
greet().zipWith(name()).map(tuple -> tuple.getT1() + tuple.getT2())
                                        .zipWith(name2()).map(tuple -> tuple.getT1() + tuple.getT2());
```

Explanation: greet() returns a String Mono and I zipped it with name(). Then I again zipped the Mono returned from the 1st map() to the third method name2() and again did a map to get the desired response.

This is just another way to zip multiple methods. But, this may not solve all problems.